# How to get the most frequent value of vector on Matlab ?

Tags: matlab, frequency

I have a vector `A` that contains let say `[1,2,2,4]`. I am looking for a way to get the most frequent value on `A` (here `2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a statistical question. The technical term for your request is [`mode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29).

So, in MATLAB, you can simply do:

```
A=[1,2,2,4]
[my_value,my_frequency]=mode(A)
```